# Python Selenium Получить Код всей страницы в лог или файл

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Вот мой код. Как правильно получить код всей страницы, чтобы потом его сохранить в файл?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
time.sleep(2)

main_page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")

print(main_page)
```

`print` выдаёт вот такое сообщение

> selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e97b70608252184611ceabc87f774282", element="bd9f8eef-fe4f-4371-85ba-9d6fc98e8abc"�

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте свойство `page_source` у WebDriver

```
main_page = driver.page_source

print(main_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй innerHTML у get_attribute

```
print(main_page.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```